# StringCases and DatePattern: something strange

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

May be that I did not understand something about *Mathematica* pattern matching, but I noticed what follow:

`st` is a string, inside the string there is a date (Italian format) so I picked this code to extract the date:

```
st = "aaa ddd f f 20/06/2018 ppp mm l l ooo";

pattern = {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"};

dateTime = StringCases[st, ___ ~~ x : DatePattern[pattern] ~~ ___ :> x]
```

> ```
> {"20/06/2018"}
> ```

Every seems to work, but if the day is 21 or 22 or 23 the command gives a wrong day:

```
someStringDate = {"01/06/2018", "02/06/2018", "10/06/2018", "11/06/2018", "12/06/2018", 
                  "20/06/2018", "21/06/2018", "22/06/2018", "30/06/2018", "31/06/2018"};

pattern = {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"};

dateTime = 
 StringCases[
  someStringDate, ___ ~~ x : DatePattern[pattern] ~~ ___ :> x]
```

> ```
> {{"1/06/2018"}, {"2/06/2018"}, {"10/06/2018"}, 
> {"1/06/2018"}, {"2/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}, {"1/06/2018"}, 
> {"2/06/2018"}, {"30/06/2018"}, {"1/06/2018"}}
> ```

Have you noticed what happens?
Does it happen to you too?

PS:
I forgot to add the version info

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Shortest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest) to find the match where [`DatePattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatePattern) is longest:

```
StringCases[
    someStringDate,
    Shortest[___] ~~ DatePattern[pattern] ~~ ___
]
```

> {{"01/06/2018"}, {"02/06/2018"}, {"10/06/2018"}, {"11/06/2018"}, 
>   {"12/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}, {"21/06/2018"}, {"22/06/2018"}, 
>   {"30/06/2018"}, {"31/06/2018"}}

Comment: Ok, it works. Thanks very much.

Comment: I'd add that if the date pattern is inside a string , above code not work. try to apply the solution to string = "Option FTSE MIB 1st Friday W 15/06/2018 CALL 21700" , not extract the date.

Answer (score 2):

Since the format of the date is explicitly known, you could construct your own `DatePattern`:

```
dp = DigitCharacter ~~ DigitCharacter;
myDatePattern = dp ~~ "/" ~~ dp ~~ "/" ~~ dp ~~ dp;

someStringDate = {"01/06/2018", "02/06/2018", "10/06/2018", 
   "11/06/2018", "12/06/2018", "20/06/2018", "21/06/2018", 
   "22/06/2018", "30/06/2018", "31/06/2018", 
   "Option FTSE MIB 1st Friday W 15/06/2018 CALL 21700", 
   "aaa ddd f f 20/06/2018 ppp mm l l ooo"};

StringCases[someStringDate, myDatePattern]
```

> ```
> {{"01/06/2018"}, {"02/06/2018"}, {"10/06/2018"}, {"11/06/2018"}, 
> {"12/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}, {"21/06/2018"}, {"22/06/2018"}, 
> {"30/06/2018"}, {"31/06/2018"}, {"15/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}}
> ```

For higher performance you could use `RegularExpression`:

```
myDatePattern2 = RegularExpression["\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}"];
StringCases[someStringDate, myDatePattern2]
```

> ```
> {{"01/06/2018"}, {"02/06/2018"}, {"10/06/2018"}, {"11/06/2018"}, 
> {"12/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}, {"21/06/2018"}, {"22/06/2018"}, 
> {"30/06/2018"}, {"31/06/2018"}, {"15/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}}
> ```

Note that without the redundant `BlankNullSequence`s everything works with `DatePattern` by default:

```
pattern = {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"};
StringCases[someStringDate, DatePattern[pattern]]
```

> ```
> {{"01/06/2018"}, {"02/06/2018"}, {"10/06/2018"}, {"11/06/2018"}, 
> {"12/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}, {"21/06/2018"}, {"22/06/2018"}, 
> {"30/06/2018"}, {"31/06/2018"}, {"15/06/2018"}, {"20/06/2018"}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks very much, I've implemented the Alexey Popkov hint , and I found that the slowdown is not due to regularExp rather than the ExceLink component when writing to excel.

Answer (score 1):

To adapt the code to the situation in which string is like that

```
string = "Option FTSE MIB 1st Friday W 15/06/2018 CALL 21700"
```

I modified the command (as suggested by Carl Woll) in this way:

```
dateTime = StringCases[string,Shortest[___] ~~ x : DatePattern[pattern] ~~ ___ :> x]
```

It works but is very slow when applied on a long string-list.